# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error in Windows 7 IIS

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

I have a simple ASP.NET Web Site. When I try to run it on Windows 7 IIS, the following error message is displayed in my browser:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server
>   Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is
>   invalid

How can I solve this problem?

[image: Web Site Error]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you get this error it means that there's probably something broken in your site's `web.config` file. IIS7 is very helpful in these cases and will usually point you roughly where the problem lies.

For example, I've deliberately broken a `web.config` on a test site by making it malformed XML:

[image]

The areas highlighted in red are providing me with a hint as to what is broken.

Without seeing the full error message from your site it would be hard to speculate what is wrong other than that something is invalid in your `web.config` file (or perhaps a parent `web.config`).

**Update:**

Based on your update and the new screenshot comment out the line indicated in red in your `web.config` file, e.g.:

```
<!-- <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> -->
```

It looks like this setting has been locked somewhere on your machine, probably in the `applicationHost.config` file in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`.

You could try unlocking this setting to allow the `web.config` setting to be used by running the following on an Administrator command line:

```
appcmd.exe unlock config /section:system.webserver/modules /commit:apphost
```

Comment: I Add a Picture of Error ...

Comment: @hosseinsinohe - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Kev. commandline to be specific %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config -section:system.webServer/modules

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that you need to unlock the **Modules** configuration section in order for it to be overridden by the web.config file in the website directory.

Try `appcmd.exe unlock config /section:system.webserver/modules /commit:apphost` , or use the **Feature Delegation** user interface to set the Modules section to read/write.